# Lecture Slides and Worksheet

Tags: beamer, presentations

I want to make a template that can easily switch between beamer slides and a worksheet.

I teach in a flipped classroom, so during class, we briefly touch on the concepts but focus mainly on working through associated problems. Currently, I make beamer slides for each concept/problem and print the slides off directly as worksheets for my class. I'm hoping that I can make a system such that:

- Problems can be printed on slides or as a worksheet (in article or exam format, most likely)
- Solutions can be typed on the slides, but don't show up on the worksheet
- Problems on the worksheet can have variable amounts of space to work out the problems (flexible formatting)

Any help in making this template before the next semester is appreciated!

Comment: You might consider a system where the problems are on separate files using macros not specific to either beamer or exam class, but which can be defined for both.  Or define macros like `\question` for beamer and `\pause` for exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the beamer article package. Comment/uncomment the two different preambles to switch between the two modes:

```
% for the article version
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

% for the beamer version
%\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some problem}
  \only<beamer>{Solution}
  \only<article>{\vskip10cm}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{next problem}
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can automate the compilation of both version using the solutions shown at https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583

For example with magic comments for TeXstudio:

```
% !TeX program = latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -jobname=% -pretex="\documentclass{beamer}" -usepretex % | latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -jobname=%_article -pretex="\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}" -usepretex % 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some problem}
  \only<beamer>{Solution}
  \only<article>{\vskip10cm}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{next problem}
  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Is there a way to add text to the article format without creating another slide in the beamer format? I added a slide to just the article format, but then it skews the number of slides in the counter.

Comment: @Emilee Text for the article does not need to be in a frame, try with `\only<article>{non beamer text}` between frames.

Comment: @Emilee Alternatively you can exclude whole frames from the numbering with `\begin{frame}<article>[noframenumbering]
only article
\end{frame}`